# Authenticate system users in Trac running nginx or standalone

Tags: nginx, trac, passwd

Is this possible to setup Trac to authenticate system users? For example users that are in `trac` group will have access to Trac.

Is this possible to user `/etc/passwd` instead of Apache's `.htpasswd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mod_auth_external](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) can be configured to use various sources including `/etc/shadow`.

Nginx has [HttpAuthPamModule](http://web.iti.upv.es/~sto/nginx/ngx_http_auth_pam_module-1.2/README.html).

Comment: It would be great but I'm not running apache :/

Comment: What *exactly* are you running then? Trac itself [does not do authentication](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAuthenticationIntroduction).

Comment: I'm using nginx